# why the total price equals NaN

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make a table that implements total price but it equals Nan

how the total is calculated:

```
  import React from 'react';
    
    const Total = (props) => {
        const {items} = props;
        let total = 0
        for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            total += parseFloat(items[i].price)
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <p className="text">Total Price: {total}</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
    
    export default Total;
```

we add items by two buttons, the add button and the + button:

[image]

[image]

the console shows no errors

here is the app.js:

```
import './App.css';
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Items from './components/item/items'
import AddItem from './components/addItem/addItem'
import Total from './components/total/total'

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    items: [
      {id:1, product:'Pen', price:2},
      {id:2, product:'Book', price:10}
    ]
  }

  deleteItem = (id) => {
    let items = this.state.items
    let i = items.findIndex(item => item.id === id)
    items.splice(i, 1)
    this.setState({items: items})
  }

  
  addItem = (item) => {
    this.setState({items: [...this.state.items, {id: this.state.items.length > 0 ? (this.state.items[this.state.items.length - 1].id + 1): 1}]
  })}
  
addItem2 = (item) => {
  this.state.items.length > 0 ? (
    item.id = this.state.items[this.state.items.length - 1].id + 1 
  ) : item.id = 1
  console.log(item.id)
  let items = this.state.items
  items.push(item)
  this.setState({items: items})
}

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <h1>Product List React App</h1>
        <div className="table">
          <Items items={this.state.items} del={this.deleteItem} add={this.addItem}/>
          <AddItem add={this.addItem2}/>
          <Total items={this.state.items}/>
          
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

here is the items.js:

```
import React from 'react';

const Items = (props) => {
    const {items, del,add} = props;
    let length = items.length
    const ListItem = length ? (
        items.map(item => {
            return(
                <div key={item.id} className="item">
                    <p  onClick={()=>add(item.id)}>+</p>
                    
                    <p>{item.product}</p>
                    <p>{item.price}</p>
                    <p className="delete" onClick={() => del(item.id)}>&times;</p>
                    
                </div>
            )
        })
    ) : (
        <div className="text">There are no items, Try to add some.</div>
    )
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="header item">
                <p>quantity</p>
                
                <p>Product</p>
                <p>Price</p>
                
                <p>Edit</p>
                
            </div>
           
            {ListItem}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Items
```

the console shows the product and the price and it shows no errors until now

Comment: one of `items[i].price` is Not A Number

Comment: Add a breakpoint at this line "total += parseFloat(items[i].price)", and step through your debugger to see what the item's price is.

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: Extra suggestions: 

1) always terminate your code lines with a semicolon. 2) Mind code readability. 
3) Avoid the ternary operator (condition ? true : false) when it's too big.
4) Prefer reactHooks instead of state. The Hook useState (ref: https://react.dev/reference/react/useState) is awesome.

keep it up and wishes for success with your calculator project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL,DR: One of the items is either a string, undefined or anything that cannot be converted into a number.

Source: [developer.mozilla.org - NaN - Description](https://By%20using%20parseFloat%20and%20checking%20if%20the%20result%20is%20a%20valid%20number%20using%20isNaN,%20you%20can%20prevent%20NaN%20values%20from%20being%20added%20to%20the%20total.%20This%20should%20help%20resolve%20the%20issue%20you%27re%20encountering.)

**Long Story Short:**

If you're getting a NaN (Not a Number) result, it indicates that at least one of the values in the items array's price property cannot be successfully converted to a number using parseFloat. To prevent this issue, you should ensure that each price value is a valid number before attempting to add it to the total.

Here's an updated version of your code that includes a check to handle potential non-numeric values:

```js
import React from 'react';

const Total = (props) => {
    const { items } = props;
    let total = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        // Ensure that the price is a valid number before adding it to the total
        const price = parseFloat(items[i].price);
        
        if (!isNaN(price)) {
            total += price;
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <p className="text">Total Price: {total}</p>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Total;
```

By using parseFloat and checking if the result is a valid number using isNaN, you can prevent NaN values from being added to the total. This should help resolve the issue you're encountering.

**Another possible case scenario:**

```js
  // this goes fine
  let someValue = "100";
  let value = parseFloat(someValue);

  // but depending on your region, this, for instance, might generate a NaN
  somevalue = "1,000.00";
  let value = parseFloat(someValue);
```

**In Your Specific Case:**

The issue causing NaN in the total price is in the addItem method where you're trying to calculate the next id. Let's fix that part:

```js
addItem = (item) => {
    const newItem = {
        id: this.state.items.length > 0 ? this.state.items[this.state.items.length - 1].id + 1 : 1,
        product: item.product,
        price: parseFloat(item.price) || 0,  // Ensure price is a valid number or default to 0
    };

    this.setState({ items: [...this.state.items, newItem] });
}
```

**Explanation**:

- Added parseFloat(item.price) || 0 to ensure that the price is converted to a valid number. If it fails, it defaults to 0.
  This modification should prevent NaN from appearing in the total price.

Answer (score 0):

Reason: your items list has an empty price. it will be either an empty string or undefined.

Solution:
correct the code as below:

```
for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        total += parseFloat(items[i].price || 0)
}
```

So, in case the price of an item is a falsy value, it will fall back to zero and avoid the NaN.

Changed line: `parseFloat(items[i].price || 0)`